# How to iterate through a data frame and for every row of that data frame, perform some actions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, for-loop

I have a scenario where I have some data in a CSV file and I need to iterate through each row and find if a particular value is found. If found then one operation is performed else another operation is performed.

This is the dataset I have used:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Teams\India.csv')

Ind = 0 SA = 0

if(dataset.loc[(dataset['Opponent']) == 'South Africa' & (dataset['Result']) == 'Won']): Ind = Ind + 1 else: SA = SA + 1
```

According to my CSV file, India Played 6 matches with South Africa and won 5 of them. So, in the end, the value of 'Ind' must be 5 and that of 'SA' must be 1.

But I am getting the following errors no matter what I do when I try to run this code:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Comment: can you also post a sample dataset you have as text? for a better reference. Thanks

Comment: @anky_91, I have posted the dataset as per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are trying to do will not work because `loc` will return all rows where your condition is **True**. they will not iterate automatically.

For what you are trying to do, it is **not necessary** to use iterrows or if statement.

try this:

```
Ind = dataset.loc[(dataset['Opponent'] == 'South Africa') & (dataset['Result'] == 'Won')].shape[0]

SA = dataset.loc[(dataset['Opponent'] != 'South Africa') | (dataset['Result'] != 'Won')].shape[0]
```

This way it will be faster than using `for loop`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can do in in one shot:

```
Ind = ((dataset['Opponent'] == 'South Africa') & (dataset['Result'] == 'Won')).sum()
SA = len(dataset) - Ind
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! But there's a small problem. It's working, but it's only generating a variable Ind with a value of 5 but not 2 variables. I don't know why!

Comment: did you run both commands? try `print(Ind, SA)` see if there's any error?

Comment: It worked! I just replaced SA with Sa and it started to work normally. IDK why!

Answer (score 0):

You need to if( (condition1 == x) & (condition2 == y)): ...

You also need some loop like

```
for row in data:
 if...:
  counter += 1
```